# Convert PNG image to raw []byte Golang

Tags: image, go, png

I have an image in PNG format which is just an array of dimensions 1x512.
I needs its raw bytes without the PNG format. How can I convert the PNG to raw bytes in Go.

I have some python code which does what I want, but I have not been able to find the same funtionality in Go:

```
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(features))
array = np.frombuffer(image.tobytes(), dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in Go? There's a png package in the standard library and the documentation shows an example of getting at the values of the individual pixels:  https://pkg.go.dev/image/png@go1.17.7 That may not be the same as the "raw bytes" format you're looking for, but it may be close.

Comment: It's not clear what your Python code does because it depends on what `Image` is, what kind of object its `open` method provides and what does the `tobytes()` method of that object does.

Comment: If you just want a quick, one-off hack, so you can actually get on with something else, you can convert a PNG to a file of raw 8-bit bytes in your Terminal/shell with **ImageMagick** using `magick INPUT.PNG -depth 8 RGB:OUTPUT.RAW` or if your data is greyscale  `magick INPUT.PNG -depth 8 GRAY:OUTPUT.RAW` The resulting files, which you would open in binary mode, will be 512*3 bytes if colour and 512 bytes if greyscale, without compression, header, padding or anything extraneous - just like your Python `tobytes()` function.

Comment: Load the image, and you can access its pixels using the `At()` method. The image will most certainly be a concrete implementation from the `image` package, so you can also access its `Pix` field, which is a slice holding the decoded image data.

Comment: That did the trick! Just needed to do one extra trick. Will post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more generic solution than yours. It uses the dimensions of the image itself instead of hardcoded values.

```go
func imageToRGBA(img image.Image) []uint8 {
    sz := img.Bounds()
    raw := make([]uint8, (sz.Max.X-sz.Min.X)*(sz.Max.Y-sz.Min.Y)*4)
    idx := 0
    for y := sz.Min.Y; y < sz.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := sz.Min.X; x < sz.Max.X; x++ {
            r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            raw[idx], raw[idx+1], raw[idx+2], raw[idx+3] = uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), uint8(a)
            idx += 4
        }
    }
    return raw
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I be found a solution:

Please note that this copies the values in the image on the x-axis and the x max is 512!

```
const FeatureVectorDimensionLength = 512

func imageToRaw(img image.Image) [2048]byte {
    var b [FeatureVectorDimensionLength*4]byte
    for i := 0; i < FeatureVectorDimensionLength; i++ {
        nrgba := img.At(i, 0).(color.NRGBA)
        idx := i*4
        b[idx], b[idx+1], b[idx+2], b[idx+3] = nrgba.R, nrgba.G, nrgba.B, nrgba.A
    }
    return b
}
```